# NAT/IPTables functionality concerns when routing across several interfaces using IP forwarding

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, linux-networking

As shown in the diagram below, I currently have three systems networked together:

```
                             Interface eno2
                             IP Addresses Assigned:
                             192.10.10.12───────────┐
                                                    │
                                                    │
                                                    │
                                                    │                       ┌─────────────────────────┐
                        ┌─────────────────────────┐ │                       │                         │
                        │                         │ │                       │                         │
                        │                         │ │                       │  Computer C             │
                        │  Computer A             ├─┤   ETH INTERFACE     ┌─┤                         │
                        │                         │ │◄───────────────────►│ │                         │
                        │                         ├─┘                     ├─┤                         │
                        │                         │                       │ │                         │
                        │                         │                       │ └─────────────────────────┘
Interface enp134s0f1    └───────────┬──┬──────────┘                       │
IP Addresses Assigned               ├─▲┘                                  │
192.168.200.12                      │ │                                   │
192.168.200.11                      │ │                                   │
                                    │ │                                   │                  Interface eno1
                 ───────────────────┘ │                                   └───────────────── IP Addresses Assigned:
                                      │                                                      192.10.10.13
                                      │                                                      192.168.200.13
                                      │                                                      5.5.5.1
                                      │
                                      │ETH
    Interface enp134s0f1              │INTERFACE
    IP Addresses Assigned             │
    192.168.200.10                    │
    5.5.5.3 ────────────────────────┐ │
                                    ├─▼─┐
                         ┌──────────┴───┴──────────┐
                         │                         │
                         │                         │
                         │  Computer B             │
                         │                         │
                         │                         │
                         │                         │
                         │                         │
                         └─────────────────────────┘
```

The objective is to have bidirectional communication between Computer C and Computer B via simple pings and ssh sessions.

For Computer B, I've added the following addresses and routes to the system:

```
ip route add 192.168.200.0/24 via 192.168.200.12
ip route add 5.5.5.1/32 via 192.168.200.12
```

Interface enp134s0f1 IP Address assigned:

- 192.168.200.12
- 5.5.5.3

For Computer A, the following addresses and routes were added along with modifications to the NAT table:

```
ip route add 192.168.200.13/32 via 192.10.10.12
ip route add 5.5.5.1/32 via 192.10.10.12

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno2 -j SNAT --to-source 192.10.10.12
```

Interface eno2 IP Address assigned:

- 192.10.10.12

Interface enp134s0f1 IP Address assigned:

- 192.168.200.11
- 192.168.200.12

For Computer C, I've added the following addresses and routes to the system:

```
ip addr add 5.5.5.1/24 dev eno1
ip addr add 192.168.200.13/24 dev eno1
ip route add 192.168.200.0/24 via 192.10.10.13 dev eno1
ip route add 5.5.5.0/24 via 192.10.10.13 dev eno1
```

Interface eno1 IP Address assigned:

- 192.10.10.13
- 192.168.200.13
- 5.5.5.1

I can currently communicate in the following direction from Computer B to Computer C with this network configuration:

```
+------------+    PING or SSH    +------------+    PING or SSH    +------------+
| Computer B |   ------------>   | Computer A |   ------------>   | Computer C |    ✓
+------------+                   +------------+                   +------------+
```

However, I'm having no luck with ping or ssh sessions in the opposite direction.

```
+------------+    PING or SSH    +------------+    PING or SSH    +------------+
| Computer B |   <------------   | Computer A |   <------------   | Computer C |    X
+------------+                   +------------+                   +------------+
```

Each computer are running different flavors of Linux as well:

- Computer A : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Computer B:  CentOS7
- Computer C:  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I am not sure if my modifications to the NAT rules are set up correctly or not.

Comment: Why not just use routing? Using the NAPT version of Nat will prevent what you want unless you do port forwarding. It adds a lot of complexity. Remember that NAT is not a substitute for routing.